# document is not defined when do "tns test android"

Tags: jasmine, nativescript

I create a `login.component.spec.ts` for my `loginComponent`. However, when I run tns test android, the `TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent)` failed. The error is below:

> NativeScript / 29 (10; Android SDK built for x86) LoginComponent
>   Should create the app FAILED
>
> Failed: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[TestComponentRenderer
>   -> InjectionToken DocumentToken]:
>
> StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[TestComponentRenderer ->
>   InjectionToken DocumentToken]: document is not defined
>
> error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [
>   'TestComponentRenderer', InjectionToken DocumentToken ] }) at Jasmine

I cannot find any result in website about my problem. Thanks for helping.

I tried to include http module since someone said the undefined document may because of http. However, it still does not work.

This is code for `login.component.spec.ts`:

```
import "core-js";

import "zone.js/dist/zone";

import "zone.js/dist/proxy";

import "zone.js/dist/sync-test";

import "zone.js/dist/async-test";

import "zone.js/dist/fake-async-test";

import "zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch";

import "zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone";


import { ComponentFixture, async, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';

import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, DebugElement} from '@angular/core';

import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular/router";

import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } 
from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';


import { LoginComponent } from '~/pages/login/login.component'; 


describe ('LoginComponent', () => {

    beforeEach(async( () => {

        TestBed.resetTestEnvironment();

        TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({

            imports: [

                RouterTestingModule

            ],
            providers: [],

            declarations: [

                LoginComponent

            ],

            schemas: [

                NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]

        }).compileComponents();

    }));

    it('Should create the app', async( () => {
        const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
        const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
        expect(app).toBeTruthy();
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `BrowserDynamicTestingModule` which is not valid for {N}. You are suppose to use `NativeScriptTestingModule` form `nativescript-angular/testing`.